# For loop is working for first index only

Tags: javascript, html

For loop is working for first element only.

I want to alert "none selected" if radio buttons are not selected.

and alert value of radio button which is selected.

```js
function btn() {
    var radio = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i = 0; i < radio.length; i++){
        if (radio[i].checked){
            alert(radio[i].value);
            return false;
        }
        if (!(radio[i].checked)){
            alert("none selected");
            return false;
        }
    }
}

document.getElementById('goBtn').addEventListener('click', btn);
```

```html
<input name="r" value="1" type="radio">
<input name="r" value="2" type="radio">
<input name="r" value="3" type="radio">
<button id="goBtn">hm</button>
```

Comment: delete return false; in the second part for not checked

Comment: It's returning false, which ends the loops ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/j375r0gs/2/ same

Comment: check here this is working fine as per your requirment : URL : jsfiddle.net/sunnysm/fxdyg64u/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's working as intended, you have a flaw in your logic.

```js
function btn() {
    var radio = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i = 0; i < radio.length; i++){
        if (radio[i].checked){
            alert(radio[i].value);
            return true;
        }
    }
   alert("none selected");
        return false;
}

document.getElementById('goBtn').addEventListener('click', btn);
```

```html
<input name="r" value="1" type="radio">
<input name="r" value="2" type="radio">
<input name="r" value="3" type="radio">
<button id="goBtn">hm</button>
```

Let your `for` return if it finds a `checked` value. Otherwise if the `for`hasn't returned then there's no value checked.

Comment: Only one radio button can be checked.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this code :

HTML :

```
<input name="r" value="1" type="radio">
<input name="r" value="2" type="radio">
<input name="r" value="3" type="radio">
<button id="goBtn">hm</button>
```

Javascript :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function btn() {
    var radio = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    var c=null;
    for (var i = 0; i < radio.length; i++){
        if (radio[i].checked){
           c = radio[i].value;
        }   
    }
    if(c !== null){
        alert(c);
    }else{
        alert("none selected");
    }
}
document.getElementById('goBtn').addEventListener('click', btn);
</script>
```

check [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sunnysm/fxdyg64u/) code

Answer (score 0):

try this code :

```
function btn() {
    var radio = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i = 0; i < radio.length; i++){
        if (radio[i].checked){
            alert(radio[i].value);
        }
        if (!(radio[i].checked)){
            alert("none selected");
        }
    }
    return false;
}

document.getElementById('goBtn').addEventListener('click', btn);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Remove `return false` from your source as it stops further execution:**

```js
function btn() {
    var radio = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i = 0; i < radio.length; i++){
        if (radio[i].checked){
            alert(radio[i].value);
        }
        if (!(radio[i].checked)){
            alert("none selected");
        }
    }
}

document.getElementById('goBtn').addEventListener('click', btn);
```

```html
<input name="r" value="1" type="radio">
<input name="r" value="2" type="radio">
<input name="r" value="3" type="radio">
<button id="goBtn">hm</button>
```